# Reliable Key Swap on Faulty Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a keyboard on which the "P" key does not work but I can't see the point of chucking it away for one defect. I therefore want to map one of the working keys to "P". This has proved a mighty, almost circular, challenge. As is typical in Linux as well, there are many solutions, all of which kind of work but not really. Ideally I want the keys swapped anytime I boot, be it to the terminal (CLI) or X/Desktop (GUI).

The "circular" problem is that's a right mission to enter the character "P" in the fixes below if you don't actually have a character P.

How best to map a working key (like section/degrees) to a non-working key like "P"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the "key code" of your working key (in my case the § called "section" or "silcrow"):

   showkey

Run this then press your working key. It should show something like:

```
keycode 41 press
keycode 41 release
```

So "41" is the keycode of my working key.

2. Map that physical keycode to your missing key.

   keycode 41 = p | sudo loadkeys

Now, if you can't actually type your missing key (e.g. "p") it get's... interesting...

The best solution I've found is to `echo $'\x70'` into a file (bash script) and then go in there and use it in a script command. Let's say you want to add the mapping to your boot routine - you would add it to the file `~/.bashrc`.

```
echo keycode 41 = p >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now you need to edit .bashrc and change the last line from:

```
echo keycode 41 = p
```

to

```
echo keycode 41 = p | sudo loadkeys
```

Now, if you reboot it should map key 41 (section) to "P".

Note 1: The following solution:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = P"
```

is a good method BUT it only works if you booted X (Desktop). It's nice because it doesn't require the dreaded sudo so you can add it to your startup `~/.bashrc`.

Note 2: Using Ctrl+Shift+u and entering 0050 (the ASCII code for "P") did not work.